# Dynamic FROM source based on query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL Server instance that has several databases. Each database has a users table. I'm attempting to write a query that will count user record counts for each database. I've gotten to a point where I can select all `database_name`, `schema_name`, and `table_name`'s into a temp table. I need to be able to select as from the results of that query though but I don't know how to go about doing that.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = 
    (SELECT ' UNION ALL
        SELECT ' +  + quotename(name,'''') + ' as database_name,
               s.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
                    AS schema_name,
               t.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as table_name 
               FROM '+ quotename(name) + '.sys.tables t
               JOIN '+ quotename(name) + '.sys.schemas s
                    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id'
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE state = 0
    ORDER BY [name] FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)');

SET @sql = stuff(@sql, 1, 12, '') + ' order by database_name, 
                                               schema_name,
                                               table_name';

DECLARE @allTables TABLE 
                   (
                        database_name NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                        schema_name NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                        table_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
                   )

INSERT INTO @allTables 
    EXEC (@sql)

SELECT
    *
--    ,(select count(*) from [database_name].[schema_name].[table_name] where isadmin = 0) as 'Users'
--    ,(select count(*) from [database_name].[schema_name].[table_name] where isadmin = 1) as 'Admins'
FROM
    @allTables 
WHERE
    table_name = 'C2_SEC_USERS'
```

This results in the following result set:

[image: result set]

I have commented out the part of the select that I need to actually count the users because it's not valid SQL. Is it possible to select `FROM` based on the result set? If so, how?

Comment: Only with more dynamic SQL. Though if you have that many databases with the same object, it sounds like you have a design flaw.

Comment: Not agreed with you @Larnu. In multitenant applications this kind of database structure is common.

Comment: In multi-tenant applications, you then don't need to amalgamate the data, @Raihan . As the OP is trying to, that infers they need to, meaning a design  flaw; they are using the database to infer something that should be defined by a column.

Comment: To the software vendor it might be part of useful information related to how many users across all tenants are using the system.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Now you need to do 2 things -

Firstly Add an identity field in your Table variable @allTables like following

```
DECLARE @allTables TABLE
(
    id  int identity(1,1),
    database_name NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    schema_name NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    table_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )
```

Secondly build dynamic query and execute

```
DECLARE 
    @CurrentId      AS INT = 0,
    @CurrentDb      AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CurrentSchema  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '';

WHILE (EXISTS(SELECT id FROM @allTables WHERE table_name = 'C2_SEC_USERS' AND id > @CurrentId))
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentId = id, @CurrentDb = [database_name], @CurrentSchema = [schema_name] FROM @allTables WHERE table_name = 'C2_SEC_USERS' AND id > @CurrentId
    SET @sql += CONCAT('SELECT ''', @CurrentDb, ''' ''database'', COUNT(*) ''User Count'' FROM ', @CurrentDb,'.',@CurrentSchema,'.C2_SEC_USERS');
    SET @sql += '
';
END;

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out by using a cursor

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @allTables TABLE (database_name NVARCHAR(MAX), schema_name NVARCHAR(MAX), table_name NVARCHAR(MAX))
select @sql = 
    (select ' UNION ALL
        SELECT ' +  quotename(name,'''') + ' as database_name,
               s.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
                    AS schema_name,
               t.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as table_name 
               FROM '+ quotename(name) + '.sys.tables t
               JOIN '+ quotename(name) + '.sys.schemas s
                    on s.schema_id = t.schema_id'
    from sys.databases
    where state=0
    order by [name]
    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)');
set @sql = stuff(@sql, 1, 12, '') + ' order by database_name, schema_name, table_name';

insert @allTables
exec (@sql)

declare @userCounts TABLE (database_name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    users int,
    admins int)
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @schemaName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @countSql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT database_name, schema_name, table_name
FROM @allTables
where table_name = 'C2_SEC_USERS' and database_name != 'master'

OPEN tables_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @dbName, @schemaName, @tableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    set @countSql = 'Select ''' + @dbName + ''' as database_name, (select count(*) from [' + @dbName + '].dbo.C2_SEC_USERS where isadmin = 0 and isinactive = 0) as users, (select count(*) from [' + @dbName + '].dbo.C2_SEC_USERS where isadmin = 1 and isinactive = 0) as admins'
    INSERT INTO @userCounts
    exec (@countSql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @dbName, @schemaName, @tableName;
END;
CLOSE tables_cursor;
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;
select * from @userCounts;
```

Comment: Not sure why you are interested with cursor where you have simpler and more optimized way to do the same. I would like to refer you the other answer provided here.